# Checkbox in fragment crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sensors, android-checkbox

I've got a checkbox in my fragment and i want that if checked made possible use the sensors to turn on the bluetooth. This is what i'm doing:

Inside the onCreate of fragment:

```
// Sensor manager 
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Radio buttons
        check = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.check1);


        check .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    if(check.isChecked()){ //do this}
                        onSensorChanged(null); // the error
                }
            }
         });
```

then:

```
@Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                getBlueOn(event); 
        }

    }
    private void getBlueOn(SensorEvent event) {
        //myVib.vibrate(70);
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        float[] values = event.values;
        // Movement
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];

        float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
            / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
        {
          if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
            return;
          }
          lastUpdate = actualTime;
          mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Blue on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
        }
      }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register this class as a listener for the orientation and
        // accelerometer sensors
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }
```

Of course in `onSensorChanged(null);` there is the crash. I don't know what write in there to call the method onestly..the checkbox is already declared as `public CheckBox check;` so it is not the problem.. Any help? 
LogCat:

```
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980): Process: com.dd.androreboot, PID: 22980
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at com.dd.androreboot.devicecontrolfragment.getBlueOn(devicecontrolfragment.java:373)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at com.dd.androreboot.devicecontrolfragment.access$1(devicecontrolfragment.java:370)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at com.dd.androreboot.devicecontrolfragment$8.onClick(devicecontrolfragment.java:340)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-17 11:42:16.979: E/AndroidRuntime(22980):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your full code for onCreateView() method

Comment: i posted the logCat. What i wrote is what is inside the onCrate. nothing else

Comment: It is in the fragment...So have your view "v" is returned in onCreteView() method.

Comment: yes, `return v;` before close the onCreteView() method